# Wordpress doesn't work properly with non standard domain names - PHPMailer fails when initialising

Tags: wp-mail, domain, smtp, phpmailer

While debugging Wordpress password reset functionality in a test environment on a local macbook, Wordpress would get stuck when sending emails.

Basically, before sending emails, a check is done in `wp-includes/pluggable.php` on sender email address, subject, etc, and further debugging showed that Wordpress is failing on  line 408 (in version 5.8.2)

```
$phpmailer->setFrom( $from_email, $from_name, false );
```

Ironically, this built-in check is performed before my custom action would correctly set the parameters:

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'my_phpmailer_example',5 );

function my_phpmailer_example( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    $phpmailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true; // Force it to use Username and Password to authenticate
    $phpmailer->Port = 587;
    $phpmailer->Username = 'me@adomain.com';
    $phpmailer->Password = 'thepassword';

    // Additional settings…
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = "tls"; // Choose SSL or TLS, if necessary for your server
    $phpmailer->From = "me@adomain.com";
    //$phpmailer->FromName = "A mailer service";
}
```

The issue occurs because that the local test domain name is non standard, meaning it misses the TLD: http://mytestdomain

Why Wordpress is refusing to use nonstandard domains? Is it required to use local private domain names which include the Top Level Domain? Or some settings are wrong in my setup?

Comment: Local test domains normally have a TLD of some kind. Have you tried just using .test?

Comment: Any TLD will work, I wonder why Wordpress took this route, they might want to avoid spending too much time to manage non standard domain names

Comment: WordPress hasn't done anything. It's PHPMailer that's failing with your domain.

Comment: Fair enough. I have renamed the local domain